# Downloading one's questions/answers

Tags: support

Silly question... how can I download the questions/answers I've participated in on mathoverflow, as listed on my homepage, onto my computer?  I'm leaving in the near future to where there is no internet, and I'd like to have them available on my laptop.  Thanks.

Comment: You can click on the "edit" buttons below your questions, and paste the LaTeX source to wherever you want.

Comment: Or indeed print each relevant page, but choose "print to file" so that you end up with a PDF or PS file stored on your computer.  But perhaps you were after a more automated method?

Comment: There's an app for exporting data from SE sites called StackPrinter. Might help.

Comment: The Stack Exchange Data Explorer lets you download results as CSV, which may be useful if you want computer readable data.

Answer (score 13):

[Stack Printer](http://stackprinter.com) copes well with [strange formatting](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=1732348&service=stackoverflow), [picture-heavy posts](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=8846&service=mathoverflow), and even [TeX](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=80199&service=mathoverflow).

Comment: This is really useful. Thankyou..